# Sublime Text style ctrl-P Equivalent in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

In Sublime Text et al, you can type **Control-P** to do an incremental file search.

In Visual Studio 2010:

**Control-i** does incremental *text* search

**Control-,** does incremental *symbol* search

**Control-Shift-f**, does *Find All Files*

What I would like is an *incremental* version of **Control-Shift-F**.

Does such a thing exist?

Comment: You've found decent answers for _any file_ in the project, but I really want fuzzy filtering for any currently open file/buffer. CTRL-TAB/CTRL-SHIFT-TAB is pretty bad, really. Sometimes.

Answer (score 35):

Visual studio 2017 comes with this feature (called `Edit.GoToAll`). The default mapping is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>,</kbd>.

To change it click `Tools -> Options` and then under Environment/Keyboard search for `GoToAll` and assign <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>:

[image: Edit.GoToAll]

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/whats-new-in-visual-studio#experience-improved-navigation-controls

Comment: In VS 2013 it's called Edit.NavigateTo, and it's also assigned to Ctlr+, by default

Comment: Confirming "GoToAll" is still true for VS 2019. Though this is a superset of a traditional Ctrl+P, and I often don't find that to be a good thing in this case (when you just want to go to a file).

Comment: "Edit.GoToFile" which can be mapped in the same way as the above answer is a more traditional file-only search behaviour like CTRL+P in Sublime or Visual Studio Code. Checked and available in VS2019 and VS2022.

Answer (score 7):

Found these two:

- [Resharper:](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/navigation_search.html#Go_to_File))

> Similar to Go to Type, Go to File (Ctrl+Shift+N) navigates you to any file within your solution. All the same search techniques and wildcards are supported.

- [VsFileNav](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/cfdf85c2-aaa4-4bdd-b8ea-e22bcc9860af)

Comment: VsFileNav is a must have

Comment: @eka808 Just stumbled across this. Glad you liked VSFileNav. I'm assuming no one really uses it anymore - I'm considering retiring it as I've kinda abandoned the project after not touching Visual Studio in longer than I can remember.

Answer (score -1):

More than a year is passed, so if you switched to VS 2012 I recommed this: http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/5437f2e7-adef-44e2-b841-78be850e763e

Comment: This is giving me 404 error "Not found".

Comment: Man, it's a link from 10 years ago...

Comment: Which again shows why it is important to add some context to a link. Like, what is this link about? In this case, it's about "Inline Navigate To", an experimental extension from the Microsoft Language Experience Team at that time. It has since been integrated in Visual Studio. Archive.org has the link archived.